# Neo4j label wont work if the label is "Tag"

Tags: neo4j, tags, label

I am creating a set of nodes and would like to incorporate the concept of a Tag in Neo4j.  When I create a node and use the specific word "Tag" for the label, it never shows up with "Tag" as the label.  I can create the node exactly the same, but use a different word other than "Tag" and it will work.  This only happens with the word "Tag", "tag", "TAG"

```
create (a:Product{name:'VirusScan Enterprise'})
create (b:Product{name:'Norton'})
create (c:Vendor{name:'Clam'})
create (d:Vendor{name:'McAfee'})
create (e:Vendor{name:'Symantec'})
create (n:Tag{name:'Antivirus'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To point out, the "Tag" label is right there, in gray in the lower left of your screenshot.

But if you're talking about the caption instead, there's nothing that enforces what property should be used as a default caption in the graph result view, and sometimes no property is chosen as a caption by default.

To choose it yourself, click on the "Tag" label (the labels are shown in the upper-left of the graph results view), and that should reveal some options at the bottom of the results view for the color and size of the nodes, and which property to use as a caption.

A node's label won't be an option for the caption, so if you want the caption to be the label, add a property whose value is the string of the label, and select that as the caption.